# how to execute function after the view is loaded swift4

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to execute a function after the view has appeared.

I have tried series of steps I tried `wait()`

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let w = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>.allocate(capacity: 20)
    self.title = "Quiz Section"
    wait(w)
    Function()
}
```

I tried `sleep()`

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sleep(10)
    Function()
}
```

I even tried `viewWillAppear` but none of them seemed to work. I want that once the view is in front then the function executes. Any help?

Comment: Have you tried `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: NEVER use any kind of "sleep" on the main queue. Very, very bad.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `viewDidAppear`

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    function()    // don't start function name with capital 
 }
```

**OR** dispatch the function in after queue if you need more duration

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let w = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>.allocate(capacity: 20)
    self.title = "Quiz Section"

     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0 ) {
          function()  
     }

}
```

Comment: If this code is in `viewDidAppear`, there is no point at all to using `asyncAfter`.

Comment: @rmaddy it's another option not both together

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    function()
}
```